# google analytics with power bi extraction

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, powerbi

I connected to google analytics api and have difference in numbers, but i connected from data studio and have the same numbers than google analytics. Metrics like users, new users, sessions etc.

Comment: Check for sampling of data if directly connected to API

Comment: i have conneted a view, no need the sample.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of  the cases where sampling just kicks in without the user knowing.

Sampling occurs when fetching data from GA API, this is how Power BI connects to the API.

Sampling usually occurs when your timeframe is larger in size or would result in too many dimensions being called.

If you have acces to GA premium, you can have access to unsampled reports or else you can divide the timeframe in shorter timeframes.

Answer (score 0):

So Power bi's connector for google analytics has a sampling issue and an API Calls limit.

Queries per day: 1,500,000 Queries per 100 seconds: 4,000

Might be better to connect Google analytics to a data warehouse such as Google BigQuery, which will help you get access to historical data that you won't be able to get with Power bi's connector. I'd suggest using a third-party connector.